# Why my parallel code is slower than the sequential

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement an online recursive parallel algorithm, which is highly parallelizable. My problem is that my python implementation does not work as I want. I have two 2D matrices where I want to update recursively every column every time a new observation is observed at time-step t.
My parallel code is like this

```
def apply_async(t):
    worker =  mp.Pool(processes = 4)
    for i in range(4):
        X[:,i,np.newaxis], b[:,i,np.newaxis] =  worker.apply_async(OULtraining, args=(train[t,i], X[:,i,np.newaxis], b[:,i,np.newaxis])).get()


    worker.close()
    worker.join()      




for t in range(p,T):
    count = 0 
    for l in range(p):
        for k in range(4):
            gn[count]=train[t-l-1,k]
            count+=1
    G = G*v +  gn @ gn.T
    Gt = (1/(t-p+1))*G

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        apply_async(t)
```

The two matrices are X and b. I want to replace directly on master's memory as each process updates recursively only one specific column of the matrices.

Why this implementation is slower than the sequential?

Is there any way to resume the process every time-step rather than killing them and create them again? Could this be the reason it is slower?

Comment: Are any of the arguments to `worker.apply_async()` perhaps large data structures?

Comment: What does it mean large? X and b are large 2D matrices, but as an argument I pass only a column of them. Then I do not think so

Comment: Ok.  I think I found your problem, see my answer below.  You need to adapt the solution to your code and data structures but the examples should clarify where this goes wrong.

Comment: Can you pelase fix the indentation? There are several errors there. Can you please make an example of the matrices you want to modify? Also, apply_async is already a method of Pool, cehck it up. Your function is recursively calling itself and generating a Pool everytime. This doesn't  look right at all.

Comment: What I want to implement is recursive as I said. And from my last question it is clear that I am aware of this that is why I ask "Is there any way to resume the process every time-step rather than killing them and create them again?". Because I want to stop it from recursively calling itself. Is there anyway so I can call the same processes to update the same column of the matrix and not kill it and create it again and again?

Comment: In addition it appears to me that there is no indentation error on the code. Do we see different things? Is this possible? Could it be something wrong with my browser?

Comment: Python is really bad at recursion. If possible you should try to do this iteratively. That will give you a significant performance post in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, your program is in practice sequential.  This is an example code snippet that is from parallelism standpoint identical to yours:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep

def gwork( qq):
    print (qq)
    sleep(1)
    return 42

p = Pool(processes=4)

for q in range(1, 10):
    p.apply_async(gwork, args=(q,)).get()
p.close()
p.join()
```

Run this and you shall notice numbers 1-9 appearing exactly once in a second. Why is this?  The reason is your `.get()`. This means every call to apply_async will in practice block in `get()` until a result is available.  It will submit one task, wait a second emulating processing delay, then return the result, after which another task is submitted to your pool.  This means there is no parallel execution ongoing at all.

Try replacing the pool management part with this:

```
results = []
for q in range(1, 10):
    res = p.apply_async(gwork, args=(q,))
    results.append(res)
p.close()
p.join()
for r in results:
    print (r.get())
```

You can now see parallelism at work, as four of your tasks are now processed simultaneously. Your loop does not block in get, as get is moved out of the loop and results are received only when they are ready.

NB: If your arguments to your worker or the return values from them are large data structures, you will lose some performance. In practice Python implements these as queues, and transmitting a lot of data via a queue is slow on relative terms compared to getting an in-memory copy of a data structure when a subprocess is forked.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. If I use that how can I be ensured that my results will be placed on the correct order? If I want to replace master's memory immediately is there any way of doing this?

Comment: As I wrote, I am not familiar with your data structures. Maybe you could instead of having a results list have a results dictionary where you would store key/value pairs so that you can from the key match the result to source data.   I probably will not be able to help much on that part, I can only explain why your program was not parallel at all.

Comment: The better way would be to dump multiprocessing.pool and replace it with ProcessPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures.  Its interface is almost indentical to multiprocessing.pool and it would allow attaching a callback when a task is completed.  You could then do the memory replacement in that callback function immediately when a task completes.

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful. Another mistake on my code as said before, is that I am recursively calling pool. Is there a way to stop and resume the same process with different inputs rather than killing and creating again the pool?

Comment: A pool executor takes a task, processes it and spits out  result. You can have a global pool instead of declaring a new pool for each iteration, but if you want to have tasks that just "hang" there and do something instead of finishing and returning a result, then you should not use pool.  A pool executor does not terminate when a task terminates, though. If your pool is global and you do not close and join it, the processes will be there, waiting for new tasks to appear.

Comment: I am trying to use the callback function to update the memory from there, but I need to pass an argument which states the column that I want to update, but the callback function only takes an argument that is the result of the process. Is there any way to pass more arguments?

Comment: No there isn't, but you can use your worker as a pass-through method. You can pass the column number to your worker as a parameter and have the worker return it unmodified alongside the actual result. Now your callback function can access this in the result future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166485/discussion-between-bekromoularo-and-hannu).

Answer (score 0):

I kept having a problem impelmenting  [Hannu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2277815/hannu)'s code:

```
results = []
for q in range(1, 10):
    res = p.apply_async(gwork, args=(q,))
    results.append(res)
p.close()
p.join()
for r in results:
    print (r.get())
```

The problem is that when the loop hits the first r.get() with an exception the whole program exits because it's not handled properly.  I've seen this method posted many times in almost the same way but always resulted in the same problem.

I ended up wrapping the r.get() in a TRY/EXCEPT block and that allowed the program to handle all the exceptions in the list and continue on as designed.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import traceback
    results = []
    pool = Pool(32)
    process_schedule_data = pool.apply_async(TSMDataProcessor().process_schedule_data, args=("Schedule",))
    # a bunch more calls like the one above but to different methods of the same class
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


    for r in results:
        try:
            r.get()
        except BaseException:
            logger.error(f"data processor exception: {traceback.format_exc()}")
```